# Condition for polynomial factoring

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I encountered a sum , prove that $x²+px+p²$ would be a factor of $(x+p)^n–x^n–p^n$ if $n$ be odd and not a multiple of $3$. I tried breaking $(x+p)^n$ by binomial but it became more complicated and also tried factoring the dividend polynomial into $(x+p)[(x+p)^{n-1}–(x^{n-1}–......p^{n-1})]$ but to no avail . Can anyone please help by telling which way of viewing this problem am i overlooking or not thinking. Can anyone please enlighten me? I don't want a full detailed solution i can work that on my own i just want the path to do it.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I just want help on the concept to prove the problem.

Comment: Note that the binomial theorem says $(x+p)^n = x^n + px(........) + p^n$. Now, can you prove it?

Comment: I have tried this as i tried breaking by binomial theorem but it seems more complicated i can't find the way how i can find condition for n being odd and not divisible by 3 .

Comment: So *everything* is complicated! Sometimes, you need to make things more complicated to get mathematical theorems! Try to prove DeMoivre's Theorem by induction or prove Heron's formula!

Comment: Can you tell @new QOpenGLWidget that doesn't the roots of equation $x²+px+p² $satisfy $γ³=p³$ and $γ²+pγ+p²=0$, where γ is the complex cube root of $p³$. If i put this relation in the polynomial i may get the result, is my concept correct.?

Comment: And, what do you even mean?

Comment: The polynomial $x²+px+p² $ if we multiply by $(x-p)$ then it becomes $x³-p³$ so it's complete factorisation is $(x-p)(x-γ)(x-γ²)$ the complex cube root of $p³$. For $(x+p)^n-x^n-y^n$ to have $x²+px+p²$ as a factor , then $γ,γ²$ must be zeros of the former polynomial also..

Comment: And? How does that help?

Comment: We can try and put $γ,γ²$ in the big dividend polynomial and check for what $n$ does it vanishes. I don't know if it will work properly but just an idea that came into my mind.

Comment: Then try the idea...

Comment: $γ,γ²$ comes out to be $ωp,ω²p$ where ω is the cube  root of unity,  now it can be done. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$(x^2+px+p^2)(x-p)=x^3-p^3$$

Now, can you do it?

Comment: Yeah, i can do it , this is the method I was writing in the comment. Thanks.